# Why doesn't Access Token have the identity of user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I am struggling with the concept of access tokens in regards to them not having the identity of the person making the request.

And i think i may be using access tokens incorrectly in my project.

The thing I don't understand is access tokens are often explained as a hotel card key to get into a room, but this analogy just doesn't make sense to me when it comes to the vast majority of requests.

For example say i have a resource for your private messages and scope read:privateMessages

If you want to do some action like read private messages, and you send me an access token I have to know who it is, as in I can't send you back someone else's private messages or all private messages.

A hotel key in this case doesn't work here, a hotel card that has scope read:gymroom write:gymroom

Then yeah you can access the room, but in any applications i have worked on I really need to know who is making the request.

To go back to private messages if you post to private messages, maybe this takes a Message and Destination, I need to know who is sending the private message and I need that from the access token...

The analogy here also breaks a bit as the sub of the access token (if access token is jwt) is usually the user id and I look that up or call the user info endpoint.

But isn't it simpler to just put the user principal name or email in the access token and save the backend from doing the lookup request on each user request?

There is no security benefit that i can see from having the email / username removed from the token, if the same token can be used to call the user info endpoint

Can I get some help with understanding this concept better as I feel maybe I am doing things incorrectly or have some kind of large misunderstanding on this concept.

I do know there are questions on this on stack overflow but I haven't found anything specifically to clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

> The analogy here also breaks a bit as the sub of the access token (if
> access token is jwt) is usually the user id and I look that up or call
> the user info endpoint.
>
> **But isn't it simpler to just put the user principal name or email in
> the access token and save the backend from doing the lookup request on
> each user request?**

Yes, you can. If I talk about specific to JWT `access token` then the primary intent behind using it for stateless authentication which mean token should contain sufficient information for the resource server to authenticate the request without datastore lookup. Oauth access token are merely random keys and  `resource server` does need `authroization server` for veriyfing the same. However, you can extends oauth authroization server with JWT support to issue the JWT token.

Comment: Thanks i think this really helps.

Can i confirm my understanding:

If access token given by authorization server is a reference token some kind of session key or some random string then we must in the resource server look this up on the authorization server, so we know who is asking for this.

If using a self reference token then we can look at the claims without looking up, (obviously needs to be authenticated as in verified that token is valid etc) but we can and likely will need those claims 

(continued below ran out of characters)

Comment: I think my source of confusion is how many things are applications in my mind... 

In oauth i think: 
The application is like the guest in the hotel analogy - it the application (SPA or whatever) shouldn't try and understand the user of the token - if its JWT or reference or whatever it shouldn't care. Just like the guest can't read the hotel key and understand the information encoded when they swipe it.

BUT the hotel system (resource server) does need to know who has this card as in they need to say "guest 102" has requested access to the gym (maybe this adds a charge etc)

(cont)

Comment: So it is then ok to add and directly use claims in to a JWT or self reference token (like the username / email) IF we are using those claims in the API/Resource server AND we verify the token is signed by the authorization server.

It is NOT ok to use the access token in the "application" or client, the application or client should use the ID token to do this and treat the access token as though it is for authorization only and doesn't contain any thing related to the user (even though it certainly does whether thats via lookup or directly encoded into it)

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

The hotel card key is a good analogy for the access token because it deals with delegation. Whoever presents the hotel card key can get in to the room. If needed there can be identity information of the original user (Resource Owner) in the access token, but in that case it does not represent the "presenter"'s identity, merely the "owner"s identity.

When you actually want to know who is entering the room (or, presenting the token), you'll need to revert to a different token and protocol such as the Identity Token in OpenID Connect.

Comment: I thought the ID token was never to be used by the backend?

When would you not need to know who is accessing the resource?

Comment: there are plenty of use cases where you don't need to know about the user accessing the resource, just the fact that it is accessed using a valid token that was issued on behalf of the resource owner; e.g. if you only care about payment for the access but not the identity of the one accessing

Comment: Is that from the perspective of the resource server though?

I feel like the cases where you don't need to know who is accessing the resource would be exceptional. Maybe for an admin resource server where you have access to everything if you present the token?

For example reading Facebook posts, images and facebook resources would need to make sure it returned your resources.

Reading your statistics or any information would almost always need to know right?

Also when would the owner be different to the presenter? Is this in the case of a stolen token?

Comment: I have been doing more reading, and I believe that it is ok to send the ID Token to the resource server IF this is a first party app (i.e how AWS cognito's authorizer works). But in a 3rd party app this should always be access token and use scopes.

If you are building an API and using auth0 or cognito or some identity management system like that which is to be used and want Role-based access control (RBAC) an ID token with those claims makes sense. 

Is this what is meant by:

"you'll need to revert to a different token and protocol such as the Identity Token in OpenID Connect."

Comment: @HansZ. That would be true in the case of App Access Tokens. However, User Access Tokens generally are specific to a user, and hence it doesn't make sense to simply be granted a User Access Token without being told what user ID it's attached to. This is particularly true since normally you want to store the access token for reuse, and typically you want to do that according to the User id.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the hotel analogy helps to understand the concept of Bearer tokens. Anyone with a valid hotel card key can enter the room. This also means that if an attacker manages to steal a Bearer token (the hotel card key), the attacker can gain access to the API (the hotel room), as long as the token is valid.

In general, the API should use the claims from a JWT for authorization, then you can skip the call to the `UserEndpoint`. Consequently, this means that the JWT should contain all the claims that the API needs for proper authorization. However, be careful when designing the token. If the access tokens are JWTs then a malicious client (e.g. from an attacker) may still try to parse the JWT and access its claims even though the client is not intended to. Or an attacker may come across the token by other means and parse it. In such cases, the application leaks data to an unauthorized party (an attacker). Data leaks can imply a violation of data protection laws or other regulations and cause troubles depending on what data the token contained. Username and email may not be a big issue regarding compliance but they can still cause security issues. For example, username and email may both be used by an attacker for personalized attacks (think of phishing emails).

Note, that it doesn't matter if the token is valid or not - the data is still there.

At Curity, we often recommend using the [Phantom Token Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/). It places an API Gateway in front of the API. The Authorization Server only issues by-reference tokens to the client (i.e. some id). When the client calls the API via the API Gateway, the latter exchanges the by-reference token for a by-value token, i.e. a JWT. In this way, no data will be leaked to the client and the API can still benefit from the JWT and its claims.